# Smoothing and flatten the metal edge

Tags: tools, metal, metal-cutting

I have a rangehood ceiling duct cover that is too long for my use so I trimed it with cirular saw. The finished edges look rough after cutting(picture attached). There are minor dent all around the edges and the it would cut my skin. I have already tried deburring tool and had little success. Is there another tool I can use to flatten the dent and smooth out the edge? [image: Metal edge]

Comment: Thin metal like this can be cut with a utility knife and straight edge    Multiple passes wil get you through with a smooth edge

Comment: install it in such a way that the edge doesn't show.

Comment: For future reference, a circular saw is the wrong tool to use here. Ideally a nibbler would be used.

Comment: A shear would be the _ideal_ tool, especially since that's probably what was originally used at the factory - not necessarily a home tool unless you're doing a lot of metal work, though. A nibbler or tin snips would have been a strong second.

Comment: @crip659 The Answer box for your answers, _please_, not the comment box! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hammer(ball preen) and a 2x4 to flatten,and a file to smooth. Place wood on one side and tap with the hammer from the other side, change side and repeat.

Probably clamp a piece of wood on both sides when filing.  Could also use an angle grinder with the two pieces of wood to give a straight edge, probably still need a file to smooth/clean up the edges well.

If possible, should try to fold over the edge.  This will give the smoothest, non cutting skin edge.

Comment: Thank you! :) OP might also consider "seaming pliers" or "sheet metal clamps". These are designed with wide, flat jaws for bending metal seams flat. Though I don't think they'll get a final edge, the metal jaws should flatten small waves that could be too stiff for a piece of soft pine 2x4 to flatten. I'd actually use them _first_ to get rid of the little ridges, then use the 2x4 to get rid of the bigger waves.